# Rails extra columns in group_by query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, grouping

My models are like this:

```
Product belongs_to Category
Product belongs_to OrderItem
```

I want to select total value of products sold in a certain day, grouped by Categorylike this:

```
@items = OrderItem.joins(:product => [:category]).where('order_items.sale_date = ?', 1.day.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).group(:'categories.name').sum(:total_value)
```

The query works fine, returning an array with Category name and Total value.

I need in the result some extra columns, like the Id of the Category. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Try `group('categories.name', 'categories.id')`

Comment: The column is there now, but I cannot access it in the view with `item.id`

Comment: After this query, `@items` should contain a `Hash` where each key is an array `[category_name, category_id]` and the value is the corresponding `sum`.

Comment: Yes, now that you mentioned it. But how can I access that in my view? I am a beginner, so excuse if this question is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to get an array of categories and corresponding sums:

```
@items = OrderItem.joins(:product => [:category]).where('order_items.sale_date = ?', 
 1.day.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).group('categories.id').
 sum(:total_value).map {|k, v| {category: Category.find(k), total_value: v}}
```

Now in the view you can use something like:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
 <p><%= item[:category].name %> - <%= item[:total_value] %></p>
<% end; %>
```